# How do I scan for and remove duplicate files in Pictures and Music folders?

Tags: file-management

I am in the process of using [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) across my systems to sync and consolidating many, many files accumulated over the years in various versions of the stardard xdg-user-dirs (Documents, Downloads, Music, Photos, Videos, etc).

What's the best way to eliminate all the duplicate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I've found so far is [DupeGuru](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/). It's free and there is a [PPA for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~hsoft/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). There are also specialized versions for picture and music files.

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hsoft/ppa
sudo apt-get-update; sudo apt-get install dupeguru-se dupeguru-me dupeguru-pe
```